# How to vertically flip the column values top to down in SQL

Tags: sql, reverse, flip

How to vertically flip the column values from top to bottom in SQL which are not in any specific order(neither asc nor desc)?

Example:  Table named 'Country' has a single column c1 with values

```
|  C1   |
---------
| JAPAN |
| NEPAL |
| INDIA |
---------
```

Now I want to display the Result-set as below:

```
|  C1   |
----------
| INDIA |
| NEPAL |
| JAPAN |
----------
```

If anyone can kindly suggest?

Comment: You might be able to use use rank and then reverse. Please give your table definition, sample records and the query you are using.

Comment: Why are the original results displayed in that specific order? Is your query ordering the results by some other column? As mentioned we need to see the table definition (CREATE TABLE ....), sample data (INSERT....) and your current query.

Comment: SQL always use some sort of ordering. You can specify ordering via `ORDER BY columnname ASC` or `ORDER BY columnname DESC`. I'd suggest your default ordering is by ID so you could try to reverse it with `ORDER BY id DESC`. For example: `SELECT * FROM Country ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: Yes, but that order isn't *guaranteed*  unless an order by clause is used, hence the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible using standard SQL (at least before 2003) because when not explicitly ordered using `ORDER BY`, a resultset is an "unordered set".

This means that the order you'll get your results is supposed to be totally random and may vary from a call to a given query to the next call to this same query. Most of the time, though, you'll simply get them the way they have been inserted into the database, but this is not guaranteed. When using advanced RDBMs, you may for instance get your entries sorted according to the last `ORDER BY` you did before.

That's also why you don't get any *row number* when querying a table. Because it just doesn't make sense.

However, since SQL 2003, OLAP functions have been introduced, including `ROW_NUMBER()`. For the reasons exposed above, it has to be "windowed" using an `OVER` clause, which breaks initial order. But you still can lean on a subquery to fetch them all, joining aside a column that will never vary:

```sql
WITH subquery(c1,c2) AS (SELECT C1,1 AS C2 FROM yourtable)
  SELECT c1
    FROM subquery
ORDER BY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY c2) DESC
```

Don't use `RANK()` as this will return the same "ex-æquo" row number if two rows are identical.

Comment: Much appreciated :)     This was asked in one of the tech rounds to know how an unordered set can be reversed in SQL which only someone with a logical thinking & good knowledge would answer. Thanks for the discussion

Comment: Glad this could have been useful. Just noticed though that subqueries are actually not required. We can oneline it in `SELECT C1 FROM yourtable ORDER BY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY 1) DESC`.